# How to use Loop inside Function corectly

Tags: python, list

i want use loop correctly inside function

This is my code :

```
def test():
    for i in range(1,10):
        return i


def check():
    print(test())
check()
```

output is 1

i want to full iteration
output : 1 ,2,4....10

Comment: "i want to full iteration output : 1 ,2,4....10" That doesn't make sense. What is the *object* you want outputted? A list? tuple? dictionary? etc etc.

Comment: You might be confused between "returning" and "printing". `return` ends the execution of the function, and your main code prints out the returned value (which will be 1, as you'd have stopped the function in the first iteration of the loop). If you want the function to _print_ ten numbers, use `print(i)` inside the loop. If you want to _return_ ten numbers, then you have to return a list, which you would not do from inside the loop.

Comment: I want the full loop to happen , when test() transfer 1 after then want to transfer 2 , 3 ,4 working while 10 times will not be fulfilled

Comment: @russiaisoccupant that doesn't **answer the question at all**. The question is, **what type of object do you want to return?**. Also, "when test() transfer 1 after then want to transfer 2 , 3 ,4 working while 10 times will not be fulfilled " is very unclear

Comment: Then you would need to use a generator, as described by wizzwizz4; but generators are an advanced topic. If you have trouble with `return`, you should probably not be going for generators just yet.

Answer (score 1):

When you return inside a function, it immediately terminates the function and returns the specified value. This means that it goes into the for loop and returns 1, then stops running. One way to get around this is to use the `yield` keyword instead of `return`.

```py
def test():
    for i in range(1, 10):
        yield i
```

This will make `test()` a generator, which can then be printed in check by unpacking its values.

```py
def check():
    print(*test())
```

Alternative ways of doing this would be to return a list in `test()` or to simply print the values within `test()` itself.

Comment: It's not _quite_ immediate, as wim pointed out in the comments on my answer. `try: return 1` `finally: return 2` will return `2`, for example. But this is well explained; welcome to Stack Overflow!

Answer (score 0):

In Python (as with *almost* all programming languages), functions can only `return` once (ish). As soon as Python encounters `return`, it'll exit the function.

Python *does* have [a feature called "generators"](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/classes.html#generators), though: with the `yield` keyword, you can (sort of) return more than once:

```py
def test():
    for i in range(1,10):
        yield i
```

To expand those values to the `print` function's arguments, [use `*` like so](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/controlflow.html#unpacking-argument-lists):

```py
def check():
    print(*test())
```

```
>>> check()
1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9
>>> sum(test())
45
```

---

[wim](https://stackoverflow.com/users/674039/wim) points out that you *can* sometimes return more than once from a function – but later `return` statements will "replace" the return value from earlier ones.

```
>>> def f():
...     try:
...         return 1
...     finally:
...         return 2
...
>>> f()
2
```

Unfortunately, CPython's optimising this too much for me to make sense of the `dis` bytecode decompilation; I have no idea how this works under the hood.

Comment: nitpick:  a finally block in a function will still execute after a return.  when the finally block also has a return statement, it's technically possible for functions to return twice (the caller will get the value from the finally block).

Comment: @wim Good point. That's something that catches people out a lot; I'll ruthlessly steal that point for my answer.

Comment: This will pass the name of the list as a whole, it's possible one by one? First 1, then 2, then 3

Comment: @russiaisoccupant Yes: you can use a `for` loop to loop over `test()`, just like how you loop over `range(1, 10)` in your question.

Answer (score -2):

If you want to return all the values in the range you can do something like this:

```
def test():
    return [i for i in range(1,10)]


def check():
    print(test())
check()
```

Comment: Yea ,  it's possible one by one? i mean First 1, then 2, then 3

Comment: this should just be `list(range(...))`

Comment: @russiaisoccupant no I thought you needed all the values together.. in that case you should use `yield`